# Action required on TLS 1.0 disablement - where do I use it in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, tls, appcenter

I need hints on where to look when it comes to salesforce disabling TLS 1.0. I recieved an email from salesforce about action required but it wasn't specified on where I use it and since im not completely sure i need help from you.

I have a .NET-application (v4.6.1) that posts data in to data extensions in marketing cloud with REST and where the API-keys is generated in appcenter. I also connected a custom activity on which I use workflowApiVersion 1.1.

I used the checklist that salesforce attached on what to verify but im not comfortable if I do not double-check that my working procedure in marketing cloud remains intact. The .NET-version is still valid but im not sure about the custom activity - are there any necessary configurations I need to do in marketing cloud or appcenter?

Apart from API-connection and the custom activity are there other suggestions that you have to take in consideration?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question;

> New production orgs created with Summer '16 or later TLS 1.0 is
>   disabled by default.
>
> New production orgs created with Summer ‘16 or later will have the
>   "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections” Critical Update
>   Console (CRUC) setting auto-enabled. This will disable TLS 1.0 by
>   default. This setting can be deactivated by the customer to enable TLS
>   1.0 as needed for TLS compatibility testing. See the article for details on user permissions required to view and change the setting.¨

The information is taken from [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1) article.